# Initializing a variable in an if-statement in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, joptionpane

I keep getting an error variable F3 may have not been intialized on the last line of code you see.

What am I doing wrong?

```
{
    Float F1,F2, F3;

    F1 = Float.parseFloat(
      JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number and press ok."));


    F2 = Float.parseFloat(
      JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a second number and press ok."));

    if(F1 >= F2)
    {

      F3=(F1 * F2) + (F1 * 2);
    }
    if(F2 >= F1)
    {
      F3 =(F1 + F2) + (F2 * 5);
    }

     DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("##.##");


  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your calculations are:" +(F3),"Caculations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Do not use variable names starting with a capital letter. Stick to the naming conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html):

> Each local variable and every blank final field must have a definitely
>   assigned value when any access of its value occurs.

Additionally from [§14.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4.2):

> If a declarator does not have an initialization expression, then every
>   reference to the variable must be preceded by execution of an
>   assignment to the variable, or a compile-time error occurs.

With the code there, it is possible that nothing ever gets assigned to `F3` before it is used (in the last line of the code snippet).

Use `F3 = null`.

Comment: Local variable can be left uninitialized. The problem was how the compiler saw the conditions which it didn't understand clearly enough to know the variable would always be initialized with a value.

Comment: How can i avoid that in the future?

Comment: @Chris By takin Pescis solution to not use 2 ifs. If you can't change that, you need to initialize your `F3`variable.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Thanks for the correction. I have updated my statement and have instead included the rules from the official doc.

Answer (score 8):

You should probably use if/else instead of if/if here, so that the compiler knows that `F3` will always be set to a value.

The following code is equivalent to your if/if statements:

```
if(F1 > F2) //The = here will always be overridden by the other if clause in your original statement so it's redundant.
{ 
  F3=(F1 * F2) + (F1 * 2);
}
else
{
  F3 =(F1 + F2) + (F2 * 5);
}
```

Comment: I was told i had to use two if statements, otherwise i would do this

Answer (score 1):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
if(F1 > F2) {
  F3 = (F1 * F2) + (F1 * 2);
} else {
  F3 = (F1 + F2) + (F2 * 5);
}
```

This should make the error go away.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable F3 assign null to it. Because of your if conditions there might be a case that this variable won't be assigned any value

Comment: Actually it will always be assigned a value, it's just that the compiler isn't smart enough to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Float F1=0,F2=0, F3=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use if-else statement and do NOT assign null to the variable.  If-else statement is better for human and compiler.  Assigning null is meaningless and makes compiler unable to check uninitialized problem for your future modifications and then you may get NullPointerException if you don't check it.