# if statement example issue getting an error in condition and in one scenario no error appearing

Tags: java

I am trying to execute the below if statement code, getting an error saying that "Variable j might not have been initialized".

Example 1:

```
public class PrimitiveTypesChallenge {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i = 10;
        int j;
        if(i == 10) {
            j = 20;
        }

        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

I initialized value for `j` variable inside the if block.

Example 2:

```
public class PrimitiveTypesChallenge {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i = 10;
        int j;
        if(i == 10) {
            j = 20; 
        }
        else {
           j = 30;
        }

        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

In both examples if conditions are true however in the example 1 getting an error and example 2 not getting an error. I am so confusing with these two scenarios. 
Can someone help me to understand the whole concept behind this?

Comment: The message is quite clear. In the first code, where do you set the value of `j` if `i` is not equal to 10?

Comment: Ask to yourself what value would `j` ended up with if `i` wasn't equal to 10 in both examples and you'll get it.

Comment: If for some magical reason `i` wouldn't be 10, `j` will be uninitialized. Compiler doesn't care if `i` can't change value in this specific example, `j` needs to be initialized in all possible paths in code.

Comment: if the specified condition is true, the code inside the block is executed and vice-versa. Also, Java compiler doesn’t let you leave a local variable uninitialized. look this blog https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/initialization-of-local-variable-in-a-conditional-block-in-java/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initializing a variable in an if-statement in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275576/initializing-a-variable-in-an-if-statement-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In example 1 the condition is always true

*We* know that, but the compiler is not smart enough to spot this fact. We know that because we read the code and evaluated the expression `i == 10` in our heads. The compiler doesn't do this. Compilers can evaluate [*constant expressions*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), and `i == 10` is not a constant expression, because it involves the *variable* `i`.

So the compiler does not know that `i == 10` is always true in example 1, so it thinks that `i == 10` could be false. In such a case, `j` would not be initialised, hence the error. This is why you need the else branch in example 2 to satisfy the compiler.

You can make `i == 10` a constant expression by saying that `i` is `final`:

```
final int i = 10;
```

So the compiler knows that `i`'s value is constant, and `j` will always be initialised, and the error will go away.